# Firebase Database Secrets on Google Apps Script

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

So, first of all, I'm asking this question because I want that someone admits or denies -whats for me is a myth- about **to use or not to use** the **deprecated firebase database secrets**.

Why this? Well, in the ***Service Accounts*** tab from the Firebase console, I can read this:

> *Databse secrets are currently deprecated ans use a legacy Firebase token generator. Update your source code with the Firebase Admin SDK*

But belows this advice, I can currently see my **secret key**. Why is this possible, if the use of this secret key is actually deprecated?

But this story, does not ends here. If a search for tutorials using Google Apps Script ([even on officials](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script)), **they use the deprecated database secret key**, but you can read this:

> *Google warns that this authentication method is deprecated. In fact you can still use this method but standard Service Accounts are more secure and are recommended. As Database secrets are easier to use, far from really deprecated and safe enough for most use cases, that's what we will use here.*

Again, how is this possible?

I want to say that I have tried:

```
function myFunction() {
  var firebaseUrl = "https://myApp.firebaseio.com/";
  var secret = "theKey";
  var database = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl, secret);
  Logger.log(database.getData());
}
```

and it works, because I cann see the data. Why if the secret is present? **This brings me to think that the use of the secret key is allowed, even it is deprecated**

Any opinions?

Comment: Deprecated doesn't mean "not working".  Deprecated means "we won't allow this to work at some point in the future, and you should consider switching to an alternative".

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I know my question could be too broad, but believe me: A lot of people have been asking all of this points when reading the tutorials and the officials guides.

Comment: Maybe it would be better to ask the individual questions separately.  Also please point me to the other places where people are asking the same questions.  They can be combined to a single canonical answer.

Comment: Dear friend, I have edited my question now, keeping the context on a single question. And when I said _a lot of people are asking_, it is a way to say, because the documentation -for me- it's not too clearly about the use of the deprecated key.

Comment: if the documentation says something is deprecated, time to switch. don't insist, otherwise you can write your own library that will satisfy every implementation you can think of.

Comment: @noogui I agree with you, but that's the point: If something in the documentation is deprecated, why they still use deprecated information in the officcial examples? It's not my intention to insist, it's only a point of view. The proof is in (eating) the pudding: still haven't received an answer.

Comment: Hello @robe007, do you know another way to fetch data from Firebase realtime database in Google Apps script?

Comment: @MuhammadSaleh The other way I've used to connect to _Firebase_ from _GAS_, it's to using this [code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/-RKpHaMPTYQ/ChQ3JRpSCAAJ), and works too. The code works without a _databse secret key_ and implements a _service account_ using the [GSApp library](https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-GSApp-Library). You get the data from firebase as a _json object_, this means that you need to go through all the object's properties by hand (`forEach, map, for ... of`) If you have any furthers questions, just let me know.

Comment: Thank You @robe007 It's helpful. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I [had this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604004/firebase-service-account-to-generate-authentication-token-for-client-side-use-wi/54614597#54614597) a ***full year and a half later***, and you are right, the information out there for using Firebase with Apps Script is outdated and misleading. I figured it out and am trying to update the information in StackOverflow and the tutorials.

> But this story, does not ends here. If a search for tutorials using Google Apps Script ([even on officials](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script)), **they use the deprecated database secret key**, but you can read this...

This link you added here is **actually a 3rd party website** by a dude named [@RomainVialard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370762/romain-vialard). His stuff has been very useful to me in the past. While the tutorials on his website have gotten outdated, the library he created still functions wonderfully and was updated semi-recently.

---

**The Issue (Server-side) - *Answer to OP's Question***

So for the server-side piece, I used the [official-ish OAuth2 Library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) to generate access tokens from a [service account with a private key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app): `https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk`. I then created a function that retrieves the token from the oauth2 library:

```
function getFirebaseService() {  
  return OAuth2.createService('Firebase')
      // Set the endpoint URL.
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

      // Set the private key and issuer. I stored mine in the PropertiesService... You could just use a variable somewhere.
      .setPrivateKey(fb_PRIVATE_KEY) //Service account private key
      .setIssuer(fb_SERVICE_EMAIL) //Service account email

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

      // Set the scopes.
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database');
}
```

With this code, I can then call `getFirebaseService().getAccessToken()` which returns a *valid* 'admin' or **Editor level access token** that can be used in a Firebase call! I use the FirebaseApp library because it's easy!

```
var service = getFirebaseService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var fb = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(fb_URL, service.getAccessToken());
    //Success! Do what ever with Firebase!!

  } else {
    Logger.log("makeToken: " + service.getLastError());
  }
```

You can also generate a client authentication token to use client-side if needed: `FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(fb_URL, service.getAccessToken()).createAuthToken(USER_EMAIL);`.

---

**Another Common Issue (Client-side)**

The main problem I had to overcome [in my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604004/firebase-service-account-to-generate-authentication-token-for-client-side-use-wi/54614597#54614597), was that Firebase Admin SDK has been upgraded to 3.x. If you **[update the tutorial code to use the 3.x version](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web)** everything works wonderfully!

```
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "<Web API Key>",
  authDomain: "<Project ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DB URL>.firebaseio.com/"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);

//userRequestToken is retrieved from server-side Romain's FirebaseApp Library linked above.
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(userRequestToken).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    console.error("authClient: ", error.code, error.message);
  });

  return {
    uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
    metadata: {
      lastSignInTime: firebase.auth().currentUser.lastSignInTime
    }
  };
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer. I'm the OP of this Q. If I'm not bad, the code you post here is about using `Firebase 3.x` in a web app, not with **appscript**. I'm seeing that now the library `FirebaseApp` is in the 30th version, but still uses the *databse secret* (`FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(url, optSecret)`) If you can explain what it needs to be change in `appscript` to make the ***everything works wonderfully!***

Comment: @robe007 Alright I have updated my answer to reflect the server-side generation of an access token using the correct method of a service account private key, *not* a database secret! Hope that answers your question finally!

Comment: I have tried and now **everything works wonderfully!**. Thanks for your answer. Clarifies a lot.

Comment: I have also posted an answer using the `GSApp`  library. I hope that helps someone out there too :)

Comment: I get this error using this solution makeToken: Exception: Invalid argument: key

Answer (score 2):

Well, now that some users have been putting an interest -**more than a full year later**- in the question (consider also the answer from **Chris W**), I post the method using the `GSApp` library, that works also without a *databse secret*:

1. Install the **[GSApp](https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-GSApp-Library)** library. To do this, go to *Resources* tab, then click on *Libraries* and paste the libraryId: **`MJ5317VIFJyKpi9HCkXOfS0MLm9v2IJHf`**
2. Create a Service Account:

   - Create a new **API Project** in your developers console, or use one associated with your script.
   - Select **APIs and Auth** -> **Credentials**.
   - Click **'Create New Client Id'**.
   - Select **Service Account** and Generate new JSON key.
   - Click **'Create Client Id'**. The JSON key will autodownload.
   - Click **'APIs'** in left menu.
   - Enable any APIs you need this service account to access.
3. Copy the contents of the downloaded **JSON key file** and paste it into your *scripts properties*. To do this, go to *File* -> *Project properties* -> *Script properties* tab. There in the field *Property* type `service_account` (or however you want to name it), and in the *Value* field paste **all the content** of the **JSON key file**.
4. Use the following code as an example:

   ```
   function myFunction() {
     var firebaseUrl = "https://YOUR-FIREBASE-PROJECT.firebaseio.com/";

     var jsonKey = JSON.parse(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("service_account"));
     var key = jsonKey.private_key;
     var clientEmail = jsonKey.client_email;  

     var serverToken = new GSApp.init(key, ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'], clientEmail);

     serverToken.addUser(clientEmail).requestToken();
     var token = serverToken.getToken(clientEmail).token;

     var dataPath = 'YOUR-FIREBASE-DATA-PATH';
     var options = {};
     var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch( firebaseUrl  + dataPath + '.json' + '?access_token=' + token, options).getContentText();
     var data = JSON.parse(result);
     var keys = Object.keys(data);

     var sheetRow = [];
     var entryKeys;

     for (index in keys) {
      sheetRow = [];
      entryKeys = Object.keys(data[keys[index]])
      for (i in entryKeys) {
       Logger.log(entryKeys[i]);
      }
     }
   }
   ```

You get the data from firebase as a *json object*, this means that you need to go through all the object's properties by hand `(forEach, map, for ... of)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so but may be anybody still needs some help on this.

If you need to replace "pin to pin" the deprecated secret because its sunset comes, the best way I found is this:

Use this to get the db

```
   let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
   let db = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(dbUrl, token);
```

This will get a token for the current user (the user who is running or the user in the name of the script is running).
This user must be added at `https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<<projectName>>/settings/iam` where you can set permissons like owner, editor, viewer...

Oh... the rules... the rules are the super basic you may were using with the secret.

```
   {
        "rules": {
            ".read": false,
            ".write": false
        }
    }
```