# Firebase service account to generate authentication token for client-side use with Google Apps Script

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script

I am having difficulty using the [FirebaseApp](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase) (a 3rd party API) to generate an authentication token that can be passed to a sidebar and used by the client to login and access my Firebase Database client-side.

I'm trying to use [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/using-secured-client-authentication-for-real-time-read-and-write-calls) but cannot get it working without using a database secret (which is being depreciated) in `makeToken()`. I'd prefer to use a service account as reflected in [this tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/authenticate-with-a-service-account). When I look at the difference between the tokens generated, the first 2 pieces separated by a '.' are identical, the last piece after the final '.' is different. The lengths are the same as well. eg:

```
//Example Generated by Database Secret: TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBv.ZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRoZSBzaG9ydCB2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4=.dGhlIG1pbmQsIHRoYXQgYnkgYSBwZXJzZXZlcmFuY2U= 
//Example Generated by Service Account: TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBv.ZGdlLCBleGNlZWRzIHRoZSBzaG9ydCB2ZWhlbWVuY2Ugb2YgYW55IGNhcm5hbCBwbGVhc3VyZS4=.IHNpbmd1bGFyIHBhc3Npb24gZnJvbSBvdGhlciBhbml=
```

I can generate the OAuth access token, pass it to FirebaseApp and generate an authentication token, but when it is passed client-side and I attempt to authenticate I get an error: `Login Failed! Error: INVALID_TOKEN: Failed to validate MAC.`

**It seems like there is a lot of misinformation and conflicting information on how this should be done.**

---

I have a `getFirebaseService()` function server-side that uses Apps Script OAuth2 Library to get an access token.

```
function getFirebaseService() {  
  return OAuth2.createService('Firebase')
      // Set the endpoint URL.
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

      // Set the private key and issuer.
      .setPrivateKey(fb_PRIVATE_KEY) //Service account private key
      .setIssuer(fb_SERVICE_EMAIL) //Service account email

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

      // Set the scopes.
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database');
}
```

I have a `makeToken()` function server-side that gets an authentication token from Firebase using the OAuth access token. I **am** able to use the `service.getAccessToken()` OAuth token server-side to access and store data. So that works, I guess my issue is creating a client auth token that's more restrictive.

```
function makeToken(){ 
  var service = getFirebaseService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {
    return FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(fb_URL, service.getAccessToken()) //Database Secret Works: "AAslhfi3MYACCESSTOKEN2930hf03ah4th8" but is being depreciated.
                    .createAuthToken(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
  } else {
    Logger.log("makeToken: " + service.getLastError());
  }
}
```

Then client-side, from the sidebar, I try to authenticate with a custom auth token retrieved server-side from `makeToken()`.

```
var userAuthToken;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (requestAuthToken) {
  userAuthToken = authenticateClient(requestAuthToken)
}).makeToken();

function authenticateClient(userRequestToken) {
  var ref = new Firebase(fb_URL);

  ref.authWithCustomToken(userRequestToken, function (error, authData) {
    if (error) {
      console.log("FB Login Failed!", error); //Error below come from here.
    }
    else {
      console.log("FB Login Succeeded!", authData);      
    }
  });

  return ref.authData.auth; 
}
```

This results in `Login Failed! Error: INVALID_TOKEN: Failed to validate MAC.`.

**Edit:** Is it possible FirebaseApp is [incorrectly generating](https://github.com/RomainVialard/FirebaseApp/blob/52e9e8167a24bfe56d09bfbae679db33b0eb41ae/src/Code.gs#L128) the JWT Authentication Token?

**Edit2:** I think the above edit is unlikely as I attempted to use the [GSApp library](https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-GSApp-Library) and had the same issue. It only seems to want the depreciated database secret, not a service account OAuth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so after a very long day I figured it out. I'm going to lay out what I ended up using for libraries and what the issue was (see the third library). The main problem was essentially that the *tutorial was outdated* and no a lot of people use Firebase in apps script.

**OAuth2 (Server-side)**
[Link](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2)

I didn't have to change anything here! It was working fine and never an issue.

---

**FirebaseApp (Server-side)**
[Link](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase)

This is a nice library and I stuck with it because it worked well (once I got it there). I had to make a change to my original code that came from the [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/authenticate-with-a-service-account) I mentioned. My code ended up like this and worked:

```
if (service.hasAccess()) {   
    return FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(fb_URL, service.getAccessToken()) //get OAuth Token
                      .createAuthToken(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), null, serviceAccount.client_email, serviceAccount.private_key);
  //... Added the null, private key, and service email parameters.
```

---

**Firebase (Client-side)**
[Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)

Alright, so ***this is where my main issue was*** -- The [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/using-secured-client-authentication-for-real-time-read-and-write-calls) I followed for client-side setup was **old**. I had to [upgrade the code](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web) on my own to use the new 3.x version:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase.js"></script>

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: "<Web API Key>",
  authDomain: "<Project ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DB URL>.firebaseio.com/"
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

With this `firebase` instance I was able to update my original `authenticateClient()` method:

```
function authenticateClient(userRequestToken) {
  firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(userRequestToken).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    console.error("authClient: ", error.code, error.message);
  });

  return {
    uid: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
    metadata: {
      lastSignInTime: firebase.auth().currentUser.lastSignInTime
    }
  }; 
}
```

That's it! I now have a `firebase` instance with a signed in user via JWT Custom Token! I came across a few people with similar issues an I hope this helps.

Comment: How are you importing the firebase script? When I do it in the html, firebase is undefined in my script. When I try eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase.js").getContentText()); in the gs script I get a syntax error (I'm pretty sure its because this script isn't compatible with google apps script node js env). Can you elaborate how exactly you are implementing <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase.js"></script>
and how you are accessing the firebase instance from there? Thanks.