# How to import firebase into google apps script, in order to create users with google provider?

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a new user in firebase via the google auth provider either automatically or by the click of a button in a sidebar addon in google sheets. The reason being is I need to get a registered uid for the user so the data that I send from sheets can be attributed to this user.

The closest thing I've found to a tutorial is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54604004/firebase-service-account-to-generate-authentication-token-for-client-side-use-wi/54614597#54614597), but I get stuck when trying to import firebase.

One method I'm seeing a lot is importing it via a script tag in the html for the sheets side bar.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: '...,
        authDomain: '...',
        databaseURL: '...',
        projectId: '...',
        storageBucket: '...',
        messagingSenderId: '...'
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I try to use the firebase variable in my .gs script it is undefined. How would I make it available to the script?

The other method I've seen is using `eval` and `URLFetchApp` in the gs script.

```
eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.2/firebase.js").getContentText());
```

This results in `SyntaxError: Missing name after . operator.`
I think this is because this library isn't intended to run on node js.

I realize that the admin sdk for firebase is intended for node js but you can't create a user with a specific provider with this method (afaik). Also I'm not sure how I would import it to Google apps script anyways. Additionally I want the user to interact with the google account selector after initiating the create user process.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually quite easy to create new users in Firebase from a Google Sheet by using the [Firebase Auth REST API](http://Firebase%20Auth%20REST%20API).

You have to issue an HTTP `POST` request to the Auth `signupNewUser` endpoint, see the detailed doc here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-create-email-password

For that you will use the `fetch()` method of the [`URLFetchApp()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) Class in your gs script, as follows:

```
function createUser() {

  const userName = "john.doe@gmail.com";
  const pwd = "xyz987";

  const createUserUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser?key=[API_KEY]" //Replace with your Web API Key

  const payload = JSON.stringify({"email": userName, "password": pwd, "returnSecureToken": true});

  const createUserResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(createUserUrl, {
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        muteHttpExceptions: true,
        payload : payload
 });

 Logger.log(JSON.parse(createUserResponse));

}
```

You will obtain the Web API Key for your Firebase project through the project settings page in your Firebase admin console.

Comment: Interesting, would you be able to expand on this to allow a user to create an account via their google account (google auth provider)? If i could get this working via the rest API then I'd be on my way I think!

Comment: Actually this looks like what I want - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential

Something like this should work right? `curl 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyAssertion?key=[API_KEY]' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-binary '{"postBody":"id_token=[GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN]&providerId=[google.com]","requestUri":"[http://localhost]","returnIdpCredential":true,"returnSecureToken":true}'`

Comment: @rt_ I don't know, I've never tried this endpoint. I could maybe have a look tomorrow, it is late for me and actually I'm going to sleep! But I'm sure you will find your way with the documentation.

Comment: Ok NP, I am close to getting it working so no worries. I'm using the above method with the official apps script OAuth2 library. Thanks Renaud!